# Github API returning NULL response on fetching User information

Tags: php, github-api

I am integrating GitHub API in my CakePhp project. I am using cURL for making request. I am able to get oAuth Code and AccessToken successfully.

But when I am trying to fetch User information by calling

> https:\api.github.com\user?access_token=7190aa11e267e0665edd367ab723d18ec34c7d64

I am getting null response.

I am pasting the response that I got below:

> headers":{"url":"https://api.github.com/user?access_token=7190aa11e267e0665edd367ab723d18ec34c7d64","content_type"**:null**,"http_code":0,"header_size":0,"request_size":0,"filetime":-1,"ssl_verify_result":0,"redirect_count":0,"total_time":0.297,"namelookup_time":0.047,"connect_time":0.297,"pretransfer_time":0,"size_upload":0,"size_download":0,"speed_download":0,"speed_upload":0,"download_content_length":-1,"upload_content_length":-1,"starttransfer_time":0,"redirect_time":0},"**response":null}

Please let me know what am I missing?

Comment: Be sure to add `curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );` as an answer and mark it as such so others can easily find a solution.

Comment: Fixed that :)
Wow, was stuck on this one for hours and as soon as I asked here it is fixed.
Problem was with cURL SSL verification. So I turned it off. 
>curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );

Please let me know if there is a better solution.

Comment: Thats a comment, not an answer.

Comment: ya Jakenoble.. thats a comment .. but as I have less than 10 reputation, I can answer my own question only after 8 hours. I will do that!!

Answer (score 0):

Posting answer to the question I raised above.

Problem was with cURL SSL verification. So I turned it off. >curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false ); Please let me know if there is a better solution.